# How to give permission to different Active Directory groups to specific views and stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

We are creating relational database and user are using different tools for reporting. We are planning to create views and give user read access. Instead of giving all user separate access we would like to create different AD groups and give permission to AD group to view specific views and Stored procedure.

Any suggestion how to give ad group access to views or SP using TSQL or GUI.

```
USE [dbname];
GO
CREATE USER test1 FROM LOGIN domainname\adgroup;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.MyViewName TO test1;
GO
```

Comment: using TSQL is with create/alter sp or views is the best way. you can store the permission on the VSS or TFS..

Comment: Copy this post title, put it in Google, and click the first link.

Comment: Does the group already exist in Security > Logins in Object Explorer. If not right click on Logins and add new login. You can type the group as the login name.

Comment: @SQLChao , I did copy the group name and created login but when i try to add them to that view I get error that syntax is not correct. Group name is test\5612 test is domain name.

Comment: @dfundako First i did that but they are either sql login or their name but this is whole active directory group.

Comment: @Justin plz post the tsql you are using to give them permission on the view

Comment: @SQLChao I have put the TSQL that I am using. I get following error. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near

Answer (score 2):

Try with brackets around the login name.

```
USE [dbname];
GO
CREATE USER test1 FROM LOGIN [domainname\adgroup];
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.MyViewName TO test1;
GO
```